# Changing string to integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The data set had "deaths" as object and I need to convert it to the INTEGER. I try to use the formula from another thread and it doesn't seem to work.

```
******Input:******
data.info()
*****Output:*****
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1270 entries, 0 to 1271
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   year            1270 non-null   object
 1   leading_cause   1270 non-null   object
 2   sex             1270 non-null   object
 3   race_ethnicity  1270 non-null   object
 4   deaths          1270 non-null   object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 59.5+ KB


****Input:****
df = pd.DataFrame({'deaths':['50','30','28']})
print (df)
df = pd.DataFrame({'deaths':['50','30','28']})
print (df)
****Output:****
  deaths
0     50
1     30
2     28

****Input:****
print (pd.to_numeric(df.deaths, errors='coerce'))
****Output:****
0    50
1    30
2    28
Name: deaths, dtype: int64

****Input:****
df.deaths = pd.to_numeric(df.deaths, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print (df)
****Output:****
   deaths
0      50
1      30
2      28

****Input:****
data.info()
****Output:****
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1270 entries, 0 to 1271
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   year            1270 non-null   object
 1   leading_cause   1270 non-null   object
 2   sex             1270 non-null   object
 3   race_ethnicity  1270 non-null   object
 4   deaths          1270 non-null   object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 59.5+ KB
```

Comment: I'm curious about the `df` and `data`. Did you assign the `df` to `data` after conversion?

Answer (score 0):

If you have nulls (np.NaN) in the column it will not convert to int type.
You need to deal with nulls first.

1 Either replace them with an int value:

```
df.deaths = df.deaths.fillna(0)
df.deaths = df.deaths.astype(int)
```

2 Or drop null values:

```
df = df[df.deaths.notna()]
df.deaths = df.deaths.astype(int)
```

3 Or (preferred) learn to live with them:

```
# make your other function accept null values
```

Comment: 4. Modify the function that ingests data so that it handles null values so there aren't any in the dataframe to begin with.